# Elasticsearch query response influenced by _id

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index with the following mappings and settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_index": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "filename",
          "filter": ["icu_folding", "edge_ngram"]
        },
        "default_search": {
          "type":"standard",
          "tokenizer": "filename",
          "filter": [
            "icu_folding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer" : {
        "filename" : {
          "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
          "type" : "pattern"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "edge_ngram" : {
          "side" : "front",
          "max_gram" : 20,
          "min_gram" : 3,
          "type" : "edgeNGram"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "metadata": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "case_insensitive_index"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following documents:

```
{"title":"P-20150531-27332_News.jpg"}
{"title":"P-20150531-27341_News.jpg"}
{"title":"P-20150531-27512_News.jpg"}
{"title":"P-20150531-27343_News.jpg"}
```

creating a document with simple numerical ids

```
111
112
113
114
```

and querying using the query

```
{
      "from" : 0,
      "size" : 10,
      "query" : {
        "match" : {
          "title" : {
            "query" : "P-20150531-27332_News.jpg",
            "type" : "boolean",
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

results in the correct scoring and ordering of the documents returned:

```
P-20150531-27332_News.jpg -> 2.780985 
P-20150531-27341_News.jpg -> 0.8262239 
P-20150531-27512_News.jpg -> 0.8120311 
P-20150531-27343_News.jpg -> 0.7687101
```

Strangely, creating the same documents with UUIDs

```
557eec2e3b00002c03de96bd
557eec0f3b00001b03de96b8
557eec0c3b00001b03de96b7
557eec123b00003a03de96ba
```

as IDs results in different scorings of the documents:

```
P-20150531-27341_News.jpg -> 2.646321
P-20150531-27332_News.jpg -> 2.1998127     
P-20150531-27512_News.jpg -> 1.7725387 
P-20150531-27343_News.jpg -> 1.2718291
```

Is this an intentional behaviour of Elasticsearch? If yes - how can I preserve the correct ordering regardless of the IDs used?

Comment: you probably want to use `default_search` as the analyzer in match query also could you try with [search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html)  with both set of ids and see if you get consistent results . if not could you set explain=true and post the response ?

Comment: I thought default_search is used in every search request if not stated otherwise. I am a bit confused that using `"analyzer":"default_search"` returns a ordering different from both of the previous orderings

Comment: I believe this is due, as keety said, to not using dfs_query_then_fetch. Check out https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch , additionally, you can use a single shard for you test

Comment: The reason why the ids change it is because the _id is used as the routing value, so with the default 5 primary shards, changing the ids will change which shard each document goes to, which can change scoring

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanations. `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` really did the trick. Also, special thanks for pointing me to the `explain=true` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query it looks like you should be using 'default_search' as the analyzer for `match query` unless you actuall intended to use `egde-ngram` on the search query too.
Example :

```
{
      "from" : 0,
      "size" : 10,
      "query" : {
        "match" : {
          "title" : {
            "query" : "P-20150531-27332_News.jpg",
            "type" : "boolean",
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
             "analyzer" : "default_search"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

`default_search` would be the default-search analyzer only if there is are no explicit `search_analyzer` or `analyzer` specified in the mapping of the field.

The article[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html#_default_analyzers) gives a good explanation of the rules by which analyzers are applied.

Also to ensure `idf` takes into account documents across shards you could use [search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch)

Comment: I was a bit confused by the different analyzer specifications. The link helped.
The real problem was actually solved by using `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch`. My query now works as expected.
Thanks a lot!